# Serious iOS-based B&W photo conversion/editing app

Tags: ios, photography

Is there any equivalent for likes of Silver Efex and Tonality for iOS? I am unable to find an app that allows sophisticated conversions. By this I mean:

1. Having a channel mixer so I can simulate the color filter effect and film sensitivity
2. Having some kind of structure/clarity/tonal contrast setting above and beyond regular contrast and sharpness
3. Having some kind of lightness curves implemented

As of today, VSCOCam has not yet implemented any of these. Huless seems to have been abandoned by its developer (no updates for more than a year), and Monophix looks like a product geared towards hobbyists more than photographers (and correct me if I am wrong).

Still, I am willing to purchase any of these if they provide the features I need.

Please let me know if you have experience using one of these apps, or any other B&W app. And I will be glad to know whether they support my required features...